# Hide/show a specific page in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hello I have a 2 pages word document with shapes and text boxes on each page. I would like to be able to hide the 2nd page or to show it.

I know we could hide a sheet on excel like bellow but I didn't find out how to do it in word :

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").visible = False
```

So I tried with this macro :

```
Sub HidePage2()
ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeBackspace
CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False 
End Sub
```

I thought I was hiding my page but in fact, it deleted it because if I replace the end of the code by the following code, it do not show my page number 2.

```
CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = True
```

I don't know how to fix my problem, could you help me?

Comment: Hiding a page in Word is not at all hard. The real problem, though, is that Word uses the active printer driver to optimize the page layout. This can result in what you've hidden not all falling on the same page when using a different printer.

Comment: But my concern is not about printing it ... So, do you know how to hide and show a page with a macro in VBA if it's not hard?

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs and sections are Word VBA objects, pages are not. You can apply a bookmark to each group of paragraphs that you want to hide, plus the page break at the bottom of the page, if there is one. Then use code like this to show or hide it:

```
Sub HidePage2()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Page2Bookmark").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End Sub

Sub ShowPage2()
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Page2Bookmark").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Macropod's comment about the printer driver is relevant, because the pagination of the document can change if you have a different active printer. Then what you thought was on page 2 could partially be on page 1 or 3. You can minimise this problem by adding page breaks before and after page 2 and ensuring that page 2 is not completely full.

Comment: Your 2 macros "HidePage2" and "ShowPage2" are perfectly working in order to hide shapes and text boxes of the page number 2 but unfortunately, the 2nd page remains and is blank. Even if I delete it and add a new blank page I couldn't get back my text boxes and shapes of the 2nd page with your macro "ShowPage2" because the bookmark has been deleted.

Comment: That simply tells us that you haven't bookmarked enough content (e.g. if you have a manual page break before the second page, that should also be included).

Comment: It may help to make the page breaks visible by choosing File>Options>Display and checking _Show all formatting marks_.

Answer (score 0):

For example, without needing to bookmark the page beforehand:

```
Sub Demo()
ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:="2").GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").Font.Hidden = True
End Sub
```